# Can I shorten the length of a table border?

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I have `border-right` on a table and I would like it to be a few pixels short from the top and bottom, preferably 80-90% height of the `<td>` as the table won't stay the same.

Like this:

[image]

Is this possible to do?

```
table{
  border-right: 1px solid #f00; 
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hY6Te/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible, as you describe it, as the `border` of an element extends (by definition) around the full border. You can, however, fake it to some extent using nested elements or with CSS-generated content.

For example, with the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>text in cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the following CSS:

```
td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    /* change the border-color to disguise the presence of the actual border
       left as #000 here, to show where the fake 'border' sits in relation to
       the actual border-right */
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
}

td::after {
    content: '';
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    width: 2px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r27DU/).

For this to be used in an email client, unfortunately a nested element is required (given the hideously primitive capacities of email clients, even now). So, the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>text in cell<div></div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS should work:

```
td {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
}

td div {
    background-color: #f00;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 3px;
    bottom: 3px;
    width: 2px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r27DU/1/).

Comment: what would be the best and cleanest way to pull this off then?

Comment: @Adsy: see the updated answer, was working on that after posting the explanation. =)

Comment: Ahh man, this code works perfect in browser view but when I view it in Outlook it disappears! :(

Comment: Ah, if you're doing this in an email client then you'll need to fall back to using nested elements I'm afraid. See the updated answer.

Comment: That does it :) thanks for your all your work!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a pseudo-element:

```
table {
    position: relative;
}

table:after {
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #f00; 
    content: "";
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    right: -1px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hY6Te/11/

Comment: if you change `table:after`'s styles to `top: 5%; bottom: 5%; right: 0;` then you'll get exactly what the op wants; +1

Answer (score 1):

Is additional markup acceptable?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hY6Te/10/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table width="200" height="100" bgcolor="#eee0e0">
        <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

---

```
table{
  border-right: 1px solid #f00; 
}

#wrapper {
    background: #eee0e0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    display: table; /* necessary for shirnk wrapping (inline-block would also work)
}
```